# How to create a text slider in a custom TextField in QML?

Tags: javascript, android, qt, qml

I want to create a custom TextField using QML, and I have it the way I want it except for one thing.  By overriding the style, I now lose the native functionality.  The most important of which, to me, is the text slider (or whatever it is called [the software component that allows you to easily select a specific point in text when using touch, such as on a mobile device]).

I do not think it really matters for the purposes of answering this question, but here is my code:

```
TextField {
implicitWidth: parent.width
inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText
style: TextFieldStyle {
   background: Rectangle {
      border.color: borderColor
      color: backgroundColor
      implicitHeight: 40 * ratio
   }
   font {
      family: fontFamily
      letterSpacing: -0.25 * ratio
      pointSize: Screen.pixelDensity < 3 ? fontSize : secondaryFontSize
      weight: fontWeight
   }
   padding {
      left: sidePadding
      right: sidePadding
   }
   selectedTextColor: blackGray
   selectionColor: verySoftBlue
   textColor: mediumGray
}
onTextChanged: isEmpty = (text === "")
```

What I want to get back is this:

[text slider on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeLlB.png)

If anyone knows how to do this, I would sure appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit more information:
I tried setting the **renderType** property of **TextFieldStyle** to **Text.NativeRendering**, but that did not bring back the slider.

Comment: If I make a `TextEdit` and only set size it looks exactly as the one from the attached image. It has an characteristic underline and slider which you need. I use Qt 5.5.1 and Android 5.1.

Comment: The thing is, when you change the style of a component you lose the original style completely, by design. Since text handles are implemented in QML and those probably lose their style. New controls will have native handles, solving this and many other, more important, issues.

Comment: Yeah, the best I have come up with so far is an extension of the comment by @Filip Hazubski where I encompass a TextInput within a Rectangle.  I can change the font properties without directly altering the style of the TextInput and the Rectangle then acts as the confining box, and I can alter its style without losing the slider.